# Science of my creature super power

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

Geo-Ionikinesis: my creature  is capable of generating plasmoid flames from thin air, not requiring the consumption of oxygen or combustible objects to maintain the flames. He has been seen being able to increase the temperature within his proximity which allows him to engulf his entire body into a flaming/molten rock form, fire concentrated plasma blasts from his hands and endure extreme heat and flame without being harmed.how would this work? what materials is my creature made of that make possible and what compounds allows these effects?

Comment: Do you have any constraints or targets for **how far from reality** this systems can be. It already seems to be pushing the limit.

Comment: The answer you're seeking is "magic". Also, I'm suspicious of the etymology of "geo-lonikinesis", but I'm not a linguist ;-)

Comment: This is just magic. The more scientifically detailed you try to explain this, the less believable it is going to seem because it's so far past the bounds of known biology AND technology.

Answer (score 1):

## He's some sort of silicon lifeform.

Carbon biology doesn't work well with extreme heat. As such, this being is some sort of rock monster made of complex silicon chains.

## They produce lots of methane and oxidizing agents.

They can squirt out from compressed internal stores burning gases which sometimes get hot enough to do plasma. Flamethrowers can burn for about 10 seconds, so assume they have about ten seconds of full massive flames that go 40 meters, and maybe a few minutes of just being burny without refueling.

Comment: The melting point of silicon is about 1700K. Typical plasmas easily reach 10000K. You'll notice as well that you will never reach the required temperatures with a measly flame temperature of around 2000K at best for methane (tho you can still melt yourself at that temp). Also, OP mentioned O2 should not be required (or any matter actually, but that just goes against the definition of plasma so we can disregard it), so that methane is gonna feel lonely without a playmate. Not even close to allowing what OP wants, but you can't be blamed, nothing short of magic will achieve the effect he's after

Comment: You get some ionization even at a low temperature. It's pretty easy to run a current across a methane flame.

Comment: Yes, if you apply enough of a voltage. But methane is not needed for that. Many hand-powered diy generators can build enough voltage to run an arc through ambient air. Having a narrow channel of plasma for the few ms it takes for discharge is not what OP is after. If you go this way, you can also have cold plasma at no more than 40 degrees (tho doing that biologically would be as unrealistic as it gets). But I think it is clear that this is not the spirit of the question. OP expects a flaming ball of plasma engulfing his character. I dare you to get that with methane alone :p

Answer (score 0):

Best I can figure, your creature has to:

1. Have some way to spawn new matter into existence, or:
2. To teleport matter from somewhere else, or:
3. You could say that there is a form of either matter or energy, like aether, that is quite abundant, but that does not register as one of the 118 atoms on the periodic table, and that your creature can simply transmute the aether into the substances required for the plasmoid flames your creature makes.

That being said, the latter two of these methods would have it so that your creature is technically not making these plasmoid flames out of thin air, although it could still appear as though it was.
So... it must be made of whichever types of materials would allow it to do one of these types of options.

Comment: Well getting the matter is one part of the problem (usually the trivial part, but with the restriction in OP's question, it is indeed made harder). But usually, the parts you'd be concerned about are: 1) where do I get enough energy to transform that matter into plasma 2) how do I survive bathing in something hotter than the melting point of any known material?